# A matrix is orthogonal if its similar matrix is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

I'm wondering how to prove this statement. Say $A=S^{-1}BS$ and $A^TA=I$,
then $(S^{-1}BS)^T S^{-1}BS = I$; so $ S^TB^T{S^{-1}}^{T} S^{-1}BS = I$, but I'm not sure about the next step.

Comment: Have you tried looking for a $2\times 2$ example/counterexample?

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please [edit] your question to tell us where you encountered this statement, what you have tried so far, and any other thoughts you may have on the problem.